# Image Editor Using PHP and Java Script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image

How to Rotate, Edit , Add Text to an image and Save it to local folder like a image editor Based on php and java script. I already tried image rotation in PHP Image Creator. But it reduces the image quality too much. If anybody knows idea to do that please share here.

Thanks

Comment: rotating bitmap images always reduces the quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas). Here is a [tutorial](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-rotate-image-using-javascript-canvas.html) for the rotation.